# Requiring Admin approval for profile changes

Tags: members, member-management, ee4

So I'm looking for some suggestions. I have a client who needs to import user data from an old application they'd like to deprecate into an EE4 installation and integrate how they listed member data the same way on the old app. Most of this stuff is easy, but one of their requests is that if a Member can edit their own profile, that those edits be approved first by a SuperAdmin before going live.

I'm looking over these three add-ons:

User: https://eeharbor.com/user
Visitor (previously Zoo Visitor): https://eeharbor.com/visitor
Zeal Smart Members: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members

And so far this functionality doesn't seem to be implemented anywhere.

The closest thought was using Visitor, which creates Channel Entries to store member data. Then I thought maybe something like Better Workflow was still out there, and I could use that so when a member profile entry is updated, it automatically goes in to the draft/review status, where a Super Admin could approve. But of course, that add-on is deprecated, and I can't seem to find any modern equivalent.

I know that EE isn't really built to be a full featured member management system, but I was hoping there was some middle ground. Has anyone successfully created anything like this? Or have any suggestions?

If an add-on like Better Workflow exists and works for EE4, I can probably build the whole thing out with Channel Entry tags and the Channel Form, as the member data being imported are members that already have accounts in the EE4 system, so I could cobble together a simple version of Visitor without it, but I still need to allow for profile edits to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help.

https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher-lite

Basically a manager of workflow logic.

Comment: I'll test it out, thanks.